# Show text in y axis kendo ui bar charts

Tags: kendo-ui

I there a way to show text series in the Y axis of the bar chart. In the demos I see numeric series but I need a way to show text series. Please refer to the screenshot attached with this post.

Thanks
Ramesh M

Comment: Please add screenshot.

Comment: where is the screenshot??